# Creating a Unittest

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hey I'm pretty new to python and I'm trying to create a Unit test for some code and I'm running into a lot of trouble, to be honest I'm wondering if the code is even testable.

```
""" 
Core employee class
"""


class Employee(object):
empCount = 0

def __init__(self, name, salary, debt, takehome):
    self.name = name
    self.salary = salary
    self.debt = debt
    self.takehome = takehome

def display_employee(self):
    print "Name : ", self.name, ",Salary: ", self.salary, "Debt: ", \
        self.debt, "Take Home: ", self.takehome


emp1 = Employee("Scott", 2000, 200, 2000-200)

emp2 = Employee("Mary", 5000, 300, 5000-300)

emp3 = Employee("Sam", 4000, 700, 4000-700)

emp4 = Employee("Sarah", 7000, 2000, 7000-200)

emp5 = Employee("Charlie", 10000, 5000, 10000-5000)

emp6 = Employee("Tony", 16000, 20000, 16000-20000)


employees = [emp1, emp2, emp3, emp4, emp5, emp6]


for employee in employees:
    employee.display_employee()


Employee.empCount = len(employees)

print "Total Employees is %d" % Employee.empCount}
```

If anyone would give me a hand that would be much appreciated, also any tips if I need to change to the code so it could run unittests on it more easily

Comment: Please [edit] your question to fix the indenting.

Comment: What is your question?  "How do I unit test this?"... There's not much there _to_ test.  There's only one method `display_employee`, which doesn't _do_ anything but print a string.  (Your class would be more usable _and_ testable if that method were called `__str__` and _returned_ the string.  There still wouldn't be much to test, though.)  Your `__init__` method doesn't do anything but set a bunch of values, and a unit test called `test_pythons_assignment_statement_works` would just be a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

I think your class is testable. But the tests are trivial since you only have an ˋ__init__` method and a display method.

The starting for unit testing is using **[unittest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html)** library.

Write a single test function for each "public" method:

```
class TestEmployee(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_init(self):
        ...

    def test_display_employee(self):
        ...
```

There are lots of tutorials on Internet, look at this one: [Testing Your Code](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/tests/).

See also: [Python testing](http://pythontesting.net/framework/unittest/unittest-introduction/)